# Firebase Array is nil

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I want to search for all documents were the Array "takePartIn" contains an specific String. After that I want to give this Array to the next VC. But the Array is always `nil`.

Here is my code:

```
func getUserArray() -> [String] {
    var users: [String]!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("users")

    ref.whereField("takePartIn", arrayContains: postID!)
        .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            guard let indeedSnapshot = snapshot else {
                print("snapshot is empty")
                return
            }
            for document in indeedSnapshot.documents {
                let documentData = document.data()
                let username = documentData["username"]
                users.append(username as! String)
            }
        }
    return users
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! UserListViewController
        print(getUserArray())
        vc.users = getUserArray()
}
```

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone concept. Add a print just before `return users`, and add a print just before `users.append(userName)`. Which one should appear in console first in your opinion? Look for "Async + Swift + Closure".

Comment: This will never work because the method to get the user array is asynchronous. You must either wait for the method to return and then segue (which is bad UX because the user must wait `n` seconds before the request to segue is fulfilled) or get the data upfront and don't allow the user to segue until that data is acquired.